# Stored procedure OUTPUT Parameter in SqlServer

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a need to use the OUTPUT parameter for providing the input to the stored procedure. I tested and found that we can use `OUTPUT` as INPUT as well.

Is there any limitations / exceptions for this case?

Comment: you mean the same parameter as input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. [Number of parameters is 2100](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx). Otherwise no.